# How to find the basis and dimension in the following problem

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the basis and dimension of $\ker(T)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ if $T:\Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^3$ be the linear transformation defined by
> $$
> T(x,y,z,t) = (x-y+z+t,x+2z-t, x+y+3z-3t).
> $$

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fslXh.jpg)

I am trying to find the basis and dimensions. Please give some idea.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you came across this problem, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts about the problem.

Comment: Please don't use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post.  [See here for why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: I tried to find when $T(x,y,z,t)=0$. and then a system of equation arises. How we can solve it

Comment: @vfhfkj I would suggest Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @vfhfkj Great, please edit your question to convey that, along with where you came across this problem

Comment: @vfhfkj I would guess that you encountered this problem in a linear algebra class, which means that you've probably already covered some method of solving a system of equations. What is that method for you? Have you tried applying that method to the system of equations that arises?

Comment: yeah, but somehow I am not geting. can you please help

Comment: @vfhfkj Sure, after you edit your question. Try to expand on "somehow I am not getting".  Exactly how far did you get into the process of solving the system of equations? Also, what exactly is the process that you were taught?